# Transforming start and end times to simple graph

Tags: mysql, mariadb, performance, performance-tuning

I've been struggeling with this problem for a while now.

I have a table `sessions` which stores the start and end times of sessions.

What I am trying to archive is a simple graph that shows the number of active sessions for the last 24 hours in a reasonable interval.

My current solution is to just query the number of active sessions every 15 minutes and store them in a seperate table with just a timestamp and a number column. This is basically duplicate data and not very exact.

The following query produces the needed result, but is very inefficient:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE timings (tstamp timestamp);
INSERT INTO timings (tstamp) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0 MINUTE), (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 15 MINUTE), [...];
SELECT tstamp, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE tstamp BETWEEN starttime AND endtime) AS 'numSessions' FROM timings;
```

I am using MariaDB 10.1. Version 10.2 adds CTEs and updating is a possibility.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @mustaccio May be the question is how to create the temporary table with index.

Comment: The current query takes about half a second even on my relatively fast development server. I'm searching for a better/faster way of getting the same output as this query.

Comment: Which is the definition of the  `TABLE sessions`, and specially, which *indexes* are defined there? Can you provide the *exeuction plan* for your query?

Comment: Check [this](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8b80bcddcfd89d1c3fdb3c8b67cccce4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded and worked a bit with CTEs. The following query runs in about half of the time.

```
WITH RECURSIVE tstamp_cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS n, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS tstamp FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1, tstamp - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE FROM tstamp_cte WHERE n < 96
)
SELECT tstamp, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE starttime < tstamp AND endtime >= tstamp OR endtime IS NULL) AS 'sessionCount'
FROM tstamp_cte
```